# Get timestamp from JSON with jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am struggling with jsonpath syntaxt. I'd like to extract two values from the following json with jsonpath.

```
{"data": {
      "1664024100": 125,
      "1664024700": 91,
      "1664025300": 186,
      "1664025900": 292,
      "1664039100": 466,
      "1664039700": 217,
      "1664110500": 98
    }
}
```

The only data I am able to extract are the values (125,91, etc.) with `$.data[*]`.

What is the correct syntax to extract the timestamp as a value and what is the right syntax to extract the value.

thanks

Comment: Which programming language you are talking about?  Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: jsonpath is not, afaik, directly linked to a specific language.  It's more a query language like xpath for XML. There are implementations for javascript, java, etc. You can check it out here: https://jsonpath.com. Some software components or middleware offer support for jsonpath to query a json document and work with the data. And im my case it's grafanas json support plug-in.

Comment: Not sure that such a questions deserves a downvote. Again it's about a syntax questions same as regex questions are. but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the property name, which is the case in my questions, it is required to use **jsonpath-plus** standard with the **~** for grabbing property names of matching items (as array)).

See https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/

So the correct syntax for my specific problem is `$.data[*~]` which gives back the timestamp.

Comment: `jsonpath-plus` is a library and not a standard. Also, as per the documentation, these are  convenient additions or elaborations not provided in the [original spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html)